# Novel or webnovel about a guy whose brother is killed by a drunk driver. After killing the driver, he commits suicide and is reincarnated

Tags: story-identification, novel, reincarnation, cultivation

The book starts with this guy's super-depressing life. He's abused and taken advantage of; it's him and his brother vs. the world. His brother is killed by a rich boy drunk driver who gets of scot-free and continues to be a pos; he kidnaps and kills him then commits suicide I think.

He is first reincarnated into the body of an recently dead alien in the middle of some high tech space battle, doesn't understand their language and they totally can tell he's not one of them, so his own alien species pretty much immediately murder him.

Can't remember if there was any more, but he then goes into the body of a baby that wasn't supposed to make it, starts cultivating from a super young age, finds a broken magic tower, goes to a magic school eventually, all while dealing with crippling mistrust of humanity and pretty much everyone he meets, which leads to him be very selfish, antisocial, violent, and murderous toward perceived enemies, etc.

He really starts some character development when he finds the tower, and later in school, when he meets people. It's a really rough road though.

Comment: He, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this story, and did you read it as a physical novel, or online? If you read it online, do you recall the name of the website?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could this be ***[Supreme Magus](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Supreme_Magus/NMw3EAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)*** (2019) by Legion20...?

From Google Books:

> **Derek McCoy was a man who spent his entire life facing adversity and injustice.** After being forced to settle with surviving rather than living, he had finally found his place in the world, until everything was taken from him one last time. **After losing his life to avenge his murdered brother, he reincarnates** until he finds a world worth living in, a world filled with magic and monsters. **Follow him along his journey, from grieving brother to alien soldier. From infant to Supreme Magus.**

I haven't read it, but the synopsis sounds pretty similar to what you've described. Also, judging by the [Google Books preview](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Supreme_Magus/NMw3EAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1), there is a "gigantic tower" within the story.

> Lith could see a gigantic tower, whose vault was so deep it could reach the bottom of the ocean, it's top so high it looked like it could touch the sky.